# Integrating Bing Maps tiles into Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

I currently managed to integrate [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) into Google Maps API as it is described in [this example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example). I wonder if I can also integrate Bing Maps *tiles* into Google Maps API. Is it possible? I could not find anything about that.

Note: I do know about [mapstraction](http://www.mapstraction.com/) but for now, I would like to stick to Google Maps API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know any of the products directly, but my guess is not without violating someone's licensing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the OpenStreetMap example that you cited, I would say that it's *possible* but it could be quite a challenge.  I would strongly advise against it since the OSM example uses version 2 of the Google API and it now officially deprecated.

But if you want to give it a try I would adapt the OSM example to point to the Bing tiles and make sure that the `tileUrlTemplate` property matches Bing's format for storing tiles.  Unfortunately, Bing uses a [quad tree format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx)  while Google uses a [coordinate based format](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Google_Maps_Coordinates) for storing tiles and accessing them via a URL.  It will be important to understand the differences if you're going to make the example work so be sure to dig into the documentation links above.  Also, MapTiler has a [fantastic visualization](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) of the different tile formats out there.  I've found this invaluable.

**Personally, I would use OpenLayers.**  Since Bing and Google both use spherical mercator, adding multiple tile sources to a single map is a trivial exercise.  [Here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/spherical-mercator.html) is an example.

Comment: +1 for OpenLayers - independent API, with access to Google, Bing, OSM, and Yahoo data

Comment: Another key point in favor of OpenLayers; using Bing/Google/OSM through OL *does not violate any of the APIs*; Using Bing's tiles in GMaps does.

Answer (score 2):

```
function TileToQuadKey ( x, y, zoom){ 
  var quad = "";
  for (var i = zoom; i > 0; i--) {
    var mask = 1 << (i - 1); 
    var cell = 0; 
    if ((x & mask) != 0) cell++; 
    if ((y & mask) != 0) cell += 2; 
    quad += cell; 
  }
  return quad; 
}

var bingMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
  name: "Bing",
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    // this returns aerial photography
    return "http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a" +
      TileToQuadKey(coord.x, coord.y,  zoom) + ".jpeg?g=1173&n=z";
      // i dont know what g=1173 means
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 21
});
```

Comment: It won't take the best out of the CDN (since you're only using the t1 server while it used to be balanced varying on the quadkey).

And like described in the previous comments, it cannot be done due to Terms of Use violation.

Comment: correct, you can go like 'ecn.t'+(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1)+'.tiles', and only do this if you have the appropriate license